# TextRenderer with Graphics transform

Tags: c#, gdi+

I've been working on a custom control and I've run into an issue with TextRenderer acting a bit surprisingly. In my OnPaint event I apply transform to the Graphics object to compensate for the scroll position like this:

```
e.Graphics.Transform = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

Then I pass the graphic object to all sub elements of the control so that they paint themselves onto it. One of this elements should draw text string onto the graphics surface. And this is where I've got an issue. This line seems to work correctly when scrolling:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, brush, new PointF(this.Rectangle.X, this.Rectangle.Y));
```

But when I use TextRenderer I get a completely different result. Heres the text line that supposed to draw the text:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, this.Rectangle, this.TextColor, TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform);
```

I thought that these two lines should produce the same result. But for some reason the second one applies the graphics transform differently and as a result, when I scroll the control all the text lines move around with different speed than the rest of the elements on the drawing surface. Could someone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y)` instead of your 2d matrix? It shouldn't really make any difference, but then again, `TextRenderer` should work properly too ...

Comment: @takrl Didn't help:( Still transforms differently for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my best guess at this: [TextRenderer.DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h60yx8s5.aspx) is GDI-based and therefore resolution-dependant. [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) is GDI+ and therefore resolution-independant. See also [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100116044507/http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx).

Since you say that the texts "move around with different speed", probably what happens is that the GDI call uses a different "default" resolution than the one your Graphics object has. That'd mean that you'd have to adjust your AutoScrollCoordinates to respect the difference between your Graphics object resolution and the "default" GDI resolution.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I've also noticed that they both return different values when trying to measure string. I guess that this might be the reason.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - were the texts also a different size than you expected them to be?

Comment: Well, I tried to draw the same string using both methods and it seems like they do differ a bit

Comment: The link to the article is dead. Can you expand on what the solution is?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Changed the link to an archived version of that page. The article basically illustrates the difference between GDI and GDI+. The solution is given in the answer.