# Compress text to fit within a control's displayed width

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# WinForms application, I have a control in which I display some text to the user on screen. For time being, assume it is a TextBox.

My requirement is if the text does not fully fit within the displayed width of the control, I want to keep reducing the font size or compress the text in some other way to fit the displayed width of the control.

I understand in extreme situations, the text may not be readable at all. But that's fine.

Can I get a code example how to achieve this?

Comment: Reason for downvote? What detail is missing in the question?

Comment: The reason is you ask for code or someone else to do your job. **You** first provide your try. Not a downvoter btw.

Comment: Just measure the string width in a loop decreasing the font size. When width is ok break the loop.

Comment: How to measure the string width?

Comment: Instead of a loop that observes the TextBox - have it fire whenever the TextBox changes.

Comment: You can't measure string width. Maybe he meant string length, which is not a good idea.

Comment: There is a better way to do this that does not compromise on usability and doesn't require anybody to write code for you.  Use a Label control instead.  Set its MaximumSize property so it can't get too large, or set AutoSize to False.  Set AutoEllipsis to True.  If the text gets too large then it automatically displays a tooltip when you hover the mouse over the control.

Comment: Actually I don't want AutoEllipsis. I want to attempt to display the full text by compressing.

Comment: @AllSolutions I'm in favor of ellipses but if there is a need, I can show you how to check if the text will fit in the textbox.

Comment: @Fabulous, please show.

Comment: @AllSolutions check my answer

Answer (score 2):

To measure the width of the font you'll have to determine it using `TextRenderer`. The following code illustrates how to achieve this, and to resize the font in the textbox.

```
var text = "Some unnecessarily long, long, long string.";

var size = default(SizeF);
// SizeF size; // Use this if you're on an older version of C# without default


do
{
    using (var font = new Font(textBox1.Font.Name, textBox1.Font.SizeInPoints))
    {
        size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font);

        if (size.Width <= textBox1.Width)
            textBox1.Text = text;
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Won't fit";
            textBox1.Font = new Font(font.Name, font.SizeInPoints - 1f);
        }
    }
} while (size.Width > textBox1.Width);
```

You may want to adjust the by how much the font size decreases if it ends up too small for your liking.

Comment: For WinForms controls, [you should use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`, not `Graphics.MeasureString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6705023/4934172).

Comment: Is there any performance penalty if there are lots of textboxes in the form? And is there a professional third party suite of controls which support such a feature of auto-shrinking text to fit the displayed width of the control?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed good catch. Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the code

Comment: @AllSolutions I'm unaware of any such tools, and you'll have to look beyond stack overflow for those. The performance degradation will depend on how many **lots** refers to. Is this text supposed to go into all textboxes, and are they the same size. If so, calculate for one and then apply the same font settings to all of them.

Comment: Nice answer! Just remember to dispose the `font` variable at the end of the loop, otherwise you'll get memory leaks.

Comment: @Fabulous, regarding third party suites of controls, on which Stack Exchange site can I post such a question? There is a site "Software Recommendations", but not sure if it will get any answers for programming related third party tools.

Comment: @AllSolutions I've never used the Software Recommendations one so I cannot assist further than the code here.

Comment: This is not tested code, there are many problems with it.  At least look at how the [framework code does it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,fec237b930cfc431).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant.

Comment: All, if possible, respond to this thread: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51322/c-winforms-grid-control-supporting-layout-of-rows-of-controls

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @HansPassant. I'm looking at that code though and at first glance it seems to be calculating the size of the control and not the contained text. I'll look into it further and make necessary adjustments.