# Compute font size to fit text into a specific width

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a changing sized image, and I would like to know which font size I should use to fit that dynamically changing size.

As you know, there is a `Graphics.MeasureString` method, which calculates the size of a string. A possible approach is measuring each font size until the best fit is found, but since I need to render a lot frames in a second, the performance impact is too high.

Is there are more efficient way to find a font size, given a specific image width?

Comment: If you can use monospaced fonts, that should be the fastest way because al characters would have the same width and no MeasureString would be needed

Comment: Calculate and list the font sizes before starting the `render` routine... Maybe `Dictionary<Bitmap, FontSize>` or `Dictionary<Size, FontSize>` so you just need to create, use, and dispose the `Font` objects while rendering ....

Comment: One solution of viability ultimately depending on your context is to found a "best" approximate size (not test all sizes), and use GPU scaling to finish to the required size.  Of course it's not perfect (may add some small resizing artifacts). Not sure how to do that with GDI+ (possible with Direct2D, you can mix both technologies).

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I am pretty sure that there isn't an approach which does not use `Graphics.MeasureString()`. At the very least, you would have to analyze a significant part of GDI+'s font rendering code in order to get an estimation of the final font size, [since it uses its own renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6705023/8528014).

Fortunately, there are ways to greatly reduce the number of `MeasureString()` calls per frame **to a small constant** (or even zero), depending on the font you are using.

---

#### Monospaced fonts

If you use a monospace font, things are easy:

1. Measure the bounds of an arbitrary character, for `n` different font sizes.
2. Divide the image width by the text length, which gives you the maximum width of a character.
3. Use the precomputed bounds list to determine the font size.

Number of calls to `MeasureString()`: `n` times during startup, `0` times per frame.

---

#### Proportional (variable spaced) fonts

If you use a proportional font with variable character sizes, stuff gets more complicated. As said in the preface, it is hard to avoid calling `MeasureString()`; however, you can **significantly reduce the required number of calls to a small constant**, by calculating and refining an estimation.

The general algorithm is:

1. Pick a maximum (`max`) font size.
2. Measure your string using the `max` font size.
3. Scale the measured string bounds to fit the image bounds. Since font sizes are roughly linear, the scale factor `s` can be used to compute an estimated font size: `est = s * max`.
4. Check for corner cases and slightly adjust the font size if the estimation `est` is not yet optimal.

An implementation may look as follows:

```
public Font GetFont(string str, Graphics g, int imgWidth, int imgHeight)
{
    // Measure with maximum sized font
    var baseSize = g.MeasureString(str, _fontCache[_maxFontSize]);

    // Downsample to actual image size
    float widthRatio = imgWidth / baseSize.Width;
    float heightRatio = imgHeight / baseSize.Height;
    float minRatio = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio);
    int estimatedFontSize = (int)(_maxFontSize * minRatio);

    // Make sure the precomputed font list is always hit
    if(estimatedFontSize > _maxFontSize)
        estimatedFontSize = _maxFontSize;
    else if(estimatedFontSize < _minFontSize)
        estimatedFontSize = _minFontSize;

    // Make sure the estimated size is not too large
    var estimatedSize = g.MeasureString(str, _fontCache[estimatedFontSize]);
    bool estimatedSizeWasReduced = false;
    while(estimatedSize.Width > imgWidth || estimatedSize.Height > imgHeight)
    {
        if(estimatedFontSize == _minFontSize)
            break;
        --estimatedFontSize;
        estimatedSizeWasReduced = true;

        estimatedSize = g.MeasureString(str, _fontCache[estimatedFontSize]);
        ++counter;
    }

    // Can we increase the size a bit?
    if(!estimatedSizeWasReduced)
    {
        while(estimatedSize.Width < imgWidth && estimatedSize.Height < imgHeight)
        {
            if(estimatedFontSize == _maxFontSize)
                break;
            ++estimatedFontSize;

            estimatedSize = g.MeasureString(str, _fontCache[estimatedFontSize]);
        }

        // We increase the size until it is larger than the image, so we need to go back one step afterwards
        if(estimatedFontSize > _minFontSize)
            --estimatedFontSize;
    }
    
    return _fontCache[estimatedFontSize];
}
```

Unfortunately the various C# online compilers do not support GDI+, but I uploaded a [self-contained sample program as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/JanWichelmann/5d1b8210a9bd5c3c25c0703ac2af6540). The program tested various different image sizes, while logging the number of calls to `MeasureString()`.

Number of calls to `MeasureString()`: `0` times during startup, `2` or `3` times per frame.

Thus, (in practice) this algorithm has **constant complexity** and is much more efficient than a linear approach, while it still finds the optimal integer font size.

This approach may be further optimized by adding additional checks in order to save another one or two `MeasureString()` calls, if the particular font and character set allow it.

**Notes**:

- The sample implementation works for both width and height; since your question indicates that you are only interested into the width, you can safely remove the height part.
- I only implemented this for integer font sizes. If the rendered text should really be as large as possible, an additional binary search between the estimated size and a small (maybe constant) offset should yield a good approximation, while keeping the number of `MeasureString()` calls small.
- In the sample implementation I preallocated all `n` `Font` objects and put them into a `_fontCache` list, for convenience. From a performance view, this may not be necessary; you may want to measure the overhead of allocating a `Font` object.
- You don't necessarily have to bound the font size at `max`. Upscaling is possible as well, but you may lose precision.
- You could exploit additional information about the content of the rendered text. For example, if there were only `m` possible strings, it might be helpful to cache their calculated font sizes.

Comment: I'm trying to render 30 frames per second. If I'm not mistaken your algorithm is O n which is not acceptable in terms of performance.

Comment: No, it isn't. You need 2 or 3 calls to `MeasureString` per frame, for a variable spaced font, which is O(1). (assuming that n = number of different font sizes)

Comment: The implementation indeed _may_ run in O(n), as the `while` loops suggest, but it never should, because the estimation is really good. I tested for a huge range of image sizes, and never exceeded 3 `MeasureString` calls (where mostly only 1 was actually needed, since the first estimation was already optimal). Thus, you could safely replace the `while` loops by `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way use ScaleTransform method. This method allows not calculate size of Font. You can use any font size and before drawing scale text to required dimensions

```
        using (Font font = new Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 45, 0, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        {
            float width = ClientSize.Width;
            float height = ClientSize.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);
            SizeF textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("Hello World", font);
            float scale = Math.Min(width / textSize.Width, height / textSize.Height);
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
        }
```